# Organizing bookshelves on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, books-generally, borer-separating

Is there an issue with organizing bookshelves on Shabbat? I could see this potentially being an issue of *borer* but I don’t know.

Comment: https://dinonline.org/2011/07/03/sorting-books-on-shabbos/#:~:text=Seforim%20may%20not%20be%20sorted,not%20be%20sorted%20on%20Shabbos.

Comment: Rb Falk said if you can see the titles of the *sefarim* it is not *borer* because you can only have *borer* if there is first a *taaruvos* and since the *sefarim* can be clearly identified this is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible to organize your bookshelf on Shabbat because of the issue of *borer* which you mention.

Peninei Halacha [writes](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/01-11-16/)

> **Just as the prohibition of Borer applies to food, it applies to other items as well, such as books**, [...] Similarly, **one may not
> sort a mix, and all the more so one may not remove the items he does
> not want.**

Dinonline [writes](https://dinonline.org/2011/07/03/sorting-books-on-shabbos/#:%7E:text=Seforim%20may%20not%20be%20sorted,not%20be%20sorted%20on%20Shabbos)

> **Seforim may not be sorted and ordered on Shabbos.** According to many
> poskim, the essential prohibition of borer is a prohibition of
> sorting, and the condition of “waste from food” is only intended to
> reveal that the act is an act of sorting and not an act of eating.
> Therefore, seforim should not be sorted on Shabbos. See Tosafos,
> Shabbos 74a; Biur Halachah 319:3; Shulchan Shlomo 319:4.

R Dovid Ribiat (The 39 melachos, vol II, p. 444) also writes

> Seforim in a shelf are considered "mixed" and may not be rearranged
> into their correct order.

**On the other side you can pull out and return books to bookshelves in the usual way** ([Peninei Halacha](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/01-11-16/))

> Books on a shelf are not considered mixed. Therefore, one may remove
> books he wishes to learn from, even if he will not actually use the
> books until hours later. One who used many books may return them to
> the bookcase on Shabbat for the sake of neatness. In the course of
> returning them, he may put each book in its proper place (R. Shlomo
> Zalman Auerbach in SSK 3, nn. 220 and 239).

Comment: Thank you @mbloch